# Network error: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, windows-networking

I am trying to connect to my Raspberry Pi through my PC using `putty`. Pi and my PC are connected through network (router) using an Ethernet cable. Till yesterday I was able to connect to this Pi, suddenly it shows error saying "*connection refused*".

I tried pinging Pi from command window and it replied fine. I checked in the Raspberry Pi configurations > Interfaces > ssh. It was Enabled.

When I checked through `netstat -an`, I could not see the IP address of the Pi.

What could be the possible error? And how to rectify it?

Comment: Perhaps the PI crashed. Did you try rebooting it?

Comment: there were some changes in router made by the network admin, which i came to know lately. She though some unknown device was added some removed the permissions.